# Spark is ignoring overridden libraries, using provided ones instead

Tags: apache-spark

I created a Spark job which requires a newer version of `commons-compress` to function. I added this to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.20</version>
</dependency>
```

And I am using `maven-shade-plugin` to bake the library into my resulting jar.

However, when I want to use things from this library, I still get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(Ljava/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel;)V
```

It seems it uses the (older) `commons-compress` which Spark uses, but ignores the one I baked into my jar.

How can I tell Spark to use my more modern version instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this type of scenario, I've had good luck using the shade plugin to actually [relocate the classes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) in the newer jar.

What effectively happens is that the newer version of the jar lives under a different hierarchical name, and the shade plugin will automatically re-write all references to that new jar within your bytecode. It's worked quite well for me in the past to avoid dependency version conflicts.

Modify your maven shade plugin's configuration with a relocation similar to the one below. You will also have to make sure that the newer version of the jar is embedded (it sounds like you've done this already).

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <relocations>
              <relocation>
                <pattern>org.apache.commons</pattern>
                <shadedPattern>org.shaded.apache.commons</shadedPattern>
              </relocation>
            </relocations>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do I have to adjust the imports as well or is this automatically handled?

Comment: You can use the traditional import path. The shade plugin will re-write all bytecode references to the new embedded class name.

Comment: Now, I get: "package org.tukaani.xz is sealed"

Comment: The sealed error was also due to different versions of org.tukaani.xz. I also added a similar rewrite rule to this package and now it works. Thanks!